Optimizing IPv4 Usage for AWS ALB with ECS
Since February 1, 2024, AWS charges $0.005 per hour for public IPv4 addresses. I want to use ECS, which requires an ALB to connect to the services. Since an ALB requires two public subnets, it will always acquire two IPv4 addresses.
Is there any way to keep the ALB within the free tier? Alternatively, is there any mechanism that allows me to use only one IPv4 address for the ALB while maintaining proper functionality?
Any suggestions or best practices to minimize these additional costs would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You could create an ALB that only has IPv6 listeners, as IPv6 addresses are currently free. Blog post copied below. If your clients can do IPv6 then problem solved. If you need IPv4, read on.
It might be possible to use the CloudFlare free plan to advertise the ALB as a CNAME and provide an IPv4 to IPv6 gateway. I know that works for EC2 instances, but I haven't tried it for load balancers, which have different DNS requirements. I'd say that's a 50/50 chance it'll work.
You could also consider using AWS CloudFront in front of your ALB to provide an IPv4 to IPv6 gateway. Again I don't know if this is possible because I haven't tried it or thought too hard about whether it's possible - I'd have to try it myself to see if it works.
If you tried either of those options it would be useful for others to report back your experience.

Application Load Balancer (ALB) now allows customers to provision load
balancers without IPv4s for clients that can connect using just IPv6s.
To connect, clients can resolve AAAA DNS records that are assigned to
ALB. The ALB is still dual stack for communication between the load
balancer and targets. With this new capability, you have the
flexibility to use both IPv4s or IPv6s for your application targets,
while avoiding IPv4 charges for clients that don’t require it.
To get started, you can either create a new dual-stack ALB without
public IPv4 or modify existing ALBs to use dual-stack without public
IPv4 using AWS APIs or console.

